# how to extract instagram username from string

Tags: javascript

I have an input field and my users are entering their instagram username in various formats

```
@username
https://www.instagram.com/username
https://www.instagram.com/username/
instagram.com/username
```

how can I extract *username* only?

with

```
(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:instagram.com|instagr.am)\/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)
```

I can extract from the URL. not sure how to search for whatever is after @

Comment: Try using a regex that looks for a prefix of `@` or the website URL. If you're still having trouble with that, come back here and show what you tried

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want a regex that matches either `@` or various forms of the URL version as a prefix to the username, followed by an optional forward-slash.

Something like this

```js
/^(?:@|(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?instagr(?:\.am|am\.com)\/)?(\w+)\/?$/
```

Breaking it down

```
^
(?:
  @                     - literal "@"
  |                     - or
  (?:https?:\/\/)?      - optional HTTP / HTTPS scheme
  (?:www\.)?            - optional "www."
  instagr(?:\.am|\.com) - "instagram.com" or "instgr.am"
  \/                    - forward-slash
)?                      - the whole prefix is optional
(\w+)                   - capture group for the username. Letters, numbers and underscores
\/?                     - optional trailing slash
$
```

```js
const inputs = [
  '@username', 
  'https://www.instagram.com/username', 
  'https://www.instagram.com/username/', 
  'instagram.com/username', 
  'handsome_jack',
  'http://example.com/handsome'
]

const rx = /^(?:@|(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?instagr(?:\.am|am\.com)\/)?(\w+)\/?$/

inputs.forEach(input => {
  let match = rx.exec(input) 
  if (match) {
    console.log(input, match[1]) 
  }
})
```

Comment: great. thanks for the explanation. i guess if there are no matches that means the username is jusr username with no @ or url. and i can just print that out. thanks again-1

Comment: @handsome sure, just make the first non-capturing group optional. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Building on top @Phil's answer. It ignores instagram usernames which has a period "." in them.

```
/^(?:@|(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?instagr(?:\.am|am\.com)\/)?([\w\.]+)\/?$/g
```

This should take care of the insta usernames with period as well.

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware they could contain dots. Thanks for the addition

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified [Phil's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61883286/4781067) into a function - all credits go to him.

**Function:**

```
function getInstagramUsernames(list) {

    const _regex = /^(?:@|(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?instagr(?:\.am|am\.com)\/)?(\w+)\/?$/;

    let results = [];

    for (const each of list) {
        let match = _regex.exec(each)
        if (match) {
            results.push(match[1])
            console.log(match[1]);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var list = [
    '@username',
    'https://www.instagram.com/usesda',
    'https://www.instagram.com/username11/',
    'instagram.com/username',
    'handsome_jack',
    'http://example.com/handsome'
]
getInstagramUsernames(list); // ['username', 'usesda', 'username11', 'username', 'handsome_jack']
```